# Why does JSR-303 bean validation require my member vars to be named a certain way?

Tags: jakarta-ee, bean-validation

Maybe this is borderline a rant rather than a question. I beat my head against this for a good while and am stunned that I didnt find any relevant hints while searching via SO and google for reasons why my validations werent firing.

Apparently the annotation based bean validation REQUIRES that your member var be named the same as your setter (with usual case variation).

Could anyone explain why this convention exists and ideally point me to somewhere that mentions this requirement in the spec/docs?

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class RantBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /***
     * if this member var is not called "name", these validations will never fire
     * calling them things like "mName", or "_name" will result in no error AND no invocation
     * of the validations.
     */
    @NotEmpty (message = "cannot be null")
    @Size (min = 2, max = 1000)
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

My perhaps naive instinct would be to put the annotation on the setter or maybe even let me inject and/or call validations within my setter and add FacesMessages to the FacesContext myself. Why is this a bad idea | why is the JSR-303 impl (with its strict naming convention) preferable?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the restriction imposed by bean validation. It is the [convention](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm) followed (and imposed) by [JavaBean specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html).

[JavaBean Conventions](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm)